# ASP.NET Core 7.0 integration tests could not find reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I have the following projects:

```
XY.Api 
XY.IntegrationTests (I use xUnit)
```

I added `XY.Api` reference to the test project and I write a basic test like this:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.Equal(1, AsdController.ASD());
    }
}
```

The result is the following:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'XY.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Why?**

---------- Edit --------

if i run this:

```
[Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            List<string> result = new();
            foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                result.Add(a.Location + "  --  " + a.FullName);
            }


            ;
            //Assert.Equal(1, UsersController.ASD());
        }
```

At the result list does not contain XY.Api.dll , but at the bin folder there is XY.Api.dll ...

----- Second update

test project .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.5.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\XY.Api\XY.Api.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Comment: What are the target frameworks of both projects?

Comment: both are net7.0

Comment: Do you see any compiler warnings after the build? In the solution explorer, do you see any exclamation marks on the "Dependencies" node of either project?

Comment: Nope nothing just the error.
I update the post, wait a minute.

Comment: Show us your `.csproj`

Comment: I updated again with .csproj file.

Comment: I think you need to check the path to `XY.Api.csproj`, your `test project .csproj` file says its 2 parent folders above. Do you have 2 XY.Api projects?

Comment: The test project is in inside a Tests folder.

Comment: Now work with Release build confug, but i dont know why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Check Project References:Make sure that the XY.IntegrationTests project is correctly linked to the XY.Api project. You can confirm this by examining the .csproj file in your test project, where there should be an entry resembling the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\XY.Api\XY.Api.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2- Also, look into the build settings: Ensure that both projects are set to build in the same configuration, such as Debug or Release. If the build configurations don't match up, it could result in the test project not locating the right build of the API project.

Comment: Holly shit, if i modify the test project Build Configuration to Release instead of Debug it is work... Api is still at Debug.
Thank you.

Comment: You are mostly welcome :)